# How do I change the HTML/CSS of a child component from parent in Angular 2+?

Tags: javascript, angular, components, parent-child, angular-directive

I have a component directive that translates a bunch of requests into a table. Is there a way to conditionally append text(both HTML and CSS) to a specified row in this child component from the parent's logic?

(parent):

```
<body>
   <child-component></child-component>
</body>
```

(child):

```
<div *ngfor = "let record in records">
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td> Class: {{ alias }} </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Clarification: If I wanted to append or edit the HTML/CSS of a row with the alias `foo` via the parent's code and show: `Class: foo (in-session)`

Edit: By "tag", I didn't mean a code tag (i.e. `<p>`), I meant appended text.

Comment: Hi Tyree, Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please elaborate on what's the intent , what have you done so far to achieve it and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Thanks. The child component is a reusable component by other parts of the app. I can't edit it directly, so I'm trying to do so from the parent. I attempted to do so with an attribute directive, but I'm unsure on how it would apply in this situation. So that leaves me stuck on how to exactly access those elements.  Does this help?

Comment: As @SiddAjmera pointed out, its still unclear what you are asking. You need to update the question with clear requirement, also you can provided the minimal reproduction of your issue on stackblitz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can come up with solution via the `@Input()` decorator of angular combined with `dynamic scss/css` class assigning in angular. In your child component you can assign dynamic css via like this

```
`[ngClass]="{'CSS-CLASS': CONDITION-HERE,'CSS-CLASS':CONDITION-HERE}"`
```

**In your specific case child component.html:**

```
<div *ngfor = "let record in records">
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td> [ngClass]="{'foo': record==record.name=='foo'}" {{ alias }} </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

PS:- You can edit the condition for class '**foo**' according to your needs.

**In your child component.ts:**

```
   export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges {

      @Input() public rercord: any[];


      constructor() {
      }
   }
```

**Whenever you want use child component in the parent component just use the following:**

```
<body>
   <child-component [records]="fetchedRecords"></child-component>
</body>
```

**Inside parent component.ts:**

```
export class ParentComponent {

         public fetchedRecords: any;


          constructor(public myService:MyService) {
          this.myService.getValues().subscribe((rowData)=>{
            this.fetchedRecords = rowData;
           });
          }
       }
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the closest solution to what I was looking for. I realized what I'm asking is not possible. I would have to edit the child component in some way to accept changes made from the parent component.